# Augmented Reality with interaction

Tags: flash, augmented-reality

I had developed 3d augmented reality applications using markers in flash and its works great.I like to move further by adding interaction with the 3D object .Is it possible ? Is there any helpful tutorial available online . Please help me to proceed further .
Thank you
Gunalan

Comment: What kind of interaction are you looking for?

Comment: Thanyou for your comment .I am looking for have virtual buttons .using hand movemnts ...

Answer (score 0):

im writing my masterthesis about this...
there are several ways. You can use hardware, track colors, use markers and so on.
that depends on what you want to do.
there is a difference between interaction with elements or a virtual menu or manipulating objects. its much easier to start with manipulating objects. for that you can use multiple markers. 
for example one marker can be used to display the object. a second one can change the size depending on the distance to the first marker. you can work with rotation.

the only thing which is very complex and almost impossible is controlling something with your eyes.
i will check my bookmarks and give you all i have. :-)
keep delevoping. are you using FLARToolkit?

so, a better answer could be given if you have a plan.
what do you want to do?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply .i am planning to do with multiple markers as you said for manipulating objects and also very keen in having virtual buttons and using hand movements we can control the object .individual  buttons for each properties scalling ,rotating ...

Comment: Yes i am Using FLARtoolkit and also using papervison 3d for 3d objects. thank you for your help ..do you is there any website or links having articles or tutorials realted to this .. thankyou very much showing interest in it